# How to display web service results as a front-end component view using Joomla 3 MVC Standards

Tags: web-services, joomla3.0, joomla-component

I need to take the results of a web service and display them in a front-end component view. I am returning the results and they are in JSON format but am not sure how the component should be built. I don't need a debate on the best way, just some advice on a good way to built this as a component i will be able to install on multiple Joomla 3 instances.

Once thing that would help greatly is some direction on where to place the code that consumes the web service. Would that be a component model? Or better as a library sitting outside the component?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you need some fast solution before learning the MVC architecture in Joomla!3 so probably a good suggestion would be to build a sample component at http://www.component-creator.com/home and then work and learn from there.

Then for the code for the webservices, it depends on what you want to do with the code, but if it's just to render in the view as you get it, use the view.html.php in your component views directory. Then, in your tmpl default view use the data to render as required.

Further you can create your own methods on the models or controllers in case you need to do something with the data, but before that, try to understand the Joomla! 3 main MVC architecture principles ;)

Comment: Thanks for the input. I did use Component Creator to gen my base component. Great tool! What I decided to do for now is create a services.php Helper so all my views can use it. In there I have methods for consuming different responses along with some true helper functions to get tokens, build URL strings, etc. So now I can create a View, call a method in the helper that returns an array of data from the request, iterate through that data, and display each item.